# when I use pg_dump to back up postgres, an error occur, how can I get rid of this error?

Tags: database, postgresql, character, backup, pg-dump

The output message is here:

> pg_dump: Dumping the contents of table "categorytype_show" failed: PQgetResult() failed.
>   pg_dump: Error message from server: ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xef 0xbb 0xbf in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "GBK"
>   pg_dump: The command was: COPY public.categorytype_show (categoryid, categorylevel, categoryname, categoryparentid, leafcategory, catalogenabled, autopayenabled, b2bvatenabled, bestofferenabled, expired, intlautosfixedcat, keywords, lsd, numofitems, orpa, orra, sellerguaranteeeligible, virtual, itemtype, isselect, imgurl, id, ctime) TO stdout;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They key is:

> ERROR: character with byte sequence 0xef 0xbb 0xbf in encoding "UTF8"
>   has no equivalent in encoding "GBK"

You have an encoding error. To overcome that, dump the data in UTF8 format as

```
pg_dump -E UTF8
```

Also consider using the `-Fc` option to pg_dump. More details at : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgdump.html

Comment: glad to have helped